# Семантическое версионирование на GiHub

Tags: git, github, версионирование

Какие теги следует использовать для сематического версионирования в git (с ключом `-a`? ) ?

На текущий момент я использую `tag -a`.

В качестве репозитория, использую GitHub.
Проект у меня достаточно большой, занимает примерно 300 МБ.
В момент создания тегов и отправке их в репозиторий, на GitHub автоматически добавляется релиз, вместе с архивом проекта.

Может ли переполниться, место из-за большого кол-ва архивов на GitHub (т.е. при выпуске патч релизов, получается новый архив) ?
Или это на самом деле не архив ? А сам архив генерируется на основе истории изменений на в git ?

Comment: я считаю не надо хранить релизы в системе версионирования кода

Comment: а как можно при отправке версий на гитхаб отключить автоматический выпуск релизов ?

Comment: наверняка, зависит от того, чем вы пользуетесь для добавления файлов в гит, еще есть .gitignore